# SFML - Code::Blocks can't see sfml-graphics (etc) files

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I really need help with installing SFML to Code::Block. 
I tried a lot of tutorials and nothing work right.

Finally I am able to compile some code (there is no problem with code, I found it on internet for testing) and everything seems ok. No errors and no warnings. But I can't run my code. The error is that program can't see the sfml-...-.dll file. But it show full path to the file, so I don't know, why it is not able to read it or use it.

Sorry, I would like to add the error here, but now it shows only in my language (which is not english) but previous state was similar error during compiling the code and code::blocks was saying that: cannot find -lsfml-graphics-d. But I certainly had the paths set and the files in the right folders. I tried several tutorials and every tutorial was quite different. So I have feeling I tried everything.

Thank you very much for answers.

Anagstrema

Comment: Put your dlls into `bin/` (or where your exe is located). Go to the project settings and set working directory to `bin/` too.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping. I still don't know, where mistake was, but I found totally different advice/tutorial. And it worked. Maybe it is because sfml-graphics etc was in different order than in others tutorial (which is strange) but it worked. Here is the way which worked for me: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=13304.msg93473#msg93473.